# Form.is_valid is always false

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I am writing a simple survey with modelForm. I have searched online for this issue too and it says that's because it's because the form is unbound... but I for simplicity I only offered one choice in models.py

Edit: form._isbound is true... so it's because of something else
      form.errors show property object at 0x03A146C0

models.py
Those are hardcoded as radio inputs in html

```
class Office(models.Model):
    Office_Space = (
        ('R1B1', 'R1B1'),
        ('R2B1', 'R2B1'),
        ('R3B1', 'R3B1'),
        ('R1B2', 'R1B2'),
        ('R2B2', 'R2B2'),
        ('R3B2', 'R3B2'),
        ('R1B3', 'R1B3'),
        ('R2B3', 'R2B3'),
        ('R3B3', 'R3B3')
    )
    space = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=Office_Space)
```

form.py

```
class officeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Office
    fields = ['space',]
```

Views.py

```
def get_SenarioChoice(request):
form_class = officeForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form_class.is_valid():
        space = request.POST.get('result')  
        response_data = {}      
        print(space+ "is valid") # here is the RxCx printed for debugging
        response_data['space'] = space
        form_class.save()
        print (connection.queries) #the SQL log          
        return JsonResponse(response_data)enter code here
return render(request, 'Front.html', {'officeform': form_class})
```

Added: template- I am very new to web-dev so when I wrote this form I did not know that it could render by itself therefore I hardcoded everything

Survey is consisted of 3 bids, each bid has 3 issues and each issue has 3 options.  (I could potentially separated them but I didn't know how so I coded them in one choicefield numbered by the issueID ("R#") + BidID ("B#"))

i.e: R1B1 = issue 1 bid 1

```
     <tr>
    <th>Bigger office</th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Bigger cubible</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R1B1" value="5" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R1B2" value="5" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R1B3" value="5" required><br></td>
    <td> </td>

    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Shared office</td>
   <td>60</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="R1B1" value="60"><br></td>
      <td id =R1C1></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R1B2" value="60"><br></td>
   <td id =R1C2></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R1B3" value="60"><br></td>
    <td id = R1C3></td>

     <td id =R1C1C></td>
     <td id =R1C2C></td>
     <td id = R1C3C></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>No change</td>
   <td>30</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R1B1" value="30" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R1B2" value="30" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R1B3" value="30" required><br></td>
    <td> </td>

    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <th>New and challenging individual assignments</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Some teamwork, some individual work</td>
   <td>80</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B1" value="80" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B2" value="80" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R2B3" value="80" required><br></td>
    <td> </td>

    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>No (i.e., no change to current situation)</td>
   <td>10</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B1" value="10"><br></td>
   <td id =R2C1></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B2" value="10"><br></td>
      <td id =R2C2></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R2B3" value="10"><br></td>
       <td id =R2C3></td>
       <td id =R2C1C></td>
       <td id =R2C2C></td>
       <td id =R2C3C></td>
   </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Mostly Group Work</td>
   <td>40</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B1" value="40" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R2B2" value="40" required><br></td>
   <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R2B3" value="40" required><br></td>
    <td> </td>

    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Working hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Yes, flextime and others</td>
   <td>50</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R3B1" value="50" required><br></td>
      <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R3B2" value="50" required><br></td>
      <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R3B3" value="50" required><br></td>
       <td> </td>

    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>No change</td>
   <td>0</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="R3B1" value="0"><br></td>
      <td id =R3C1></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R3B2" value="0"><br></td>
      <td id =R3C2></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R3B3" value="0"><br></td>
       <td id =R3C3></td>
       <td id =R3C1C></td>
       <td id =R3C2C></td>
       <td id =R3C3C></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Work more</td>
   <td>10</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R3B1" value="10" required><br></td>
      <td> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="R3B2" value="10" required><br></td>
      <td> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="R3B3" value="10" required><br></td>
       <td> </td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the controller in `views.py` where you instantiate and process the form.

Comment: Thanks for replying,it's updated now.

Comment: Why does it need to be a JsonResponse?

Comment: Need to process the data and do some web layout changes; also the survey is supposed to be constantly updating (no page refresh)

Comment: Then I suggest, we need to see your template too

Comment: It's added now... apologize in advance for the messiness as I had no idea what I got myself into...

Comment: json alone is not going to give you page refresh, this is where ajax would come into play. Are you hard coding all that html?

Comment: Yes the template just posted is all hardcoded... but json manages the show/hide, buttonclick (submit) and html.append

Comment: json is just data... do you mean javascript

Comment: Take a look at this, it works, but it does not use json
https://ghostbin.com/paste/n5z3u